# Git Branches to Folder Merging

Tags: git, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I have a Git repo with 2 branches - branch_a, branch_b

```
branch_a holds new.php
branch_b holds app.html
```

Now, I need to deploy code on server for CI/CD using Gitlab. 
Technically I want to merge these 2 branches into one another branch - develop into 2 folders - backend and frontend

```
-develop
--backend -> new.php (from branch_a)
--frontend -> app.html (from branch_a)
```

Now, is this something achievable / suggested approach?

Comment: Be careful not to confuse branches with folders. They have little to do with each other.

Comment: I understand. Think of like this:
- laravel (branch)
- angular(branch)

Now, these needs to be made like this:
front-end (folder)
back-end (folder)

Answer (score 0):

You have your back-end files and front-end files in another?

Move all your files in your front-end branch into a 'front-end' directory and all your files in your back-end branch into a 'back-end' directory. Now you can just merge the branches.

If there are any files that are shared between the two branches then you'll get a merge conflict which you'll need to manually resolve. You'll need to decide whether the file should be duplicated across both directories, only exist in one or maybe be moved back to the root.

Comment: Could you explain why?